# Read a file, skip unwanted lines & add into a List

Tags: python

I have the following code where I scan every line and put in a list. If the line matches 
a string "New changes", I don't want to put in the list. Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    mainlist = [line.strip() for line in f]
```

Comment: Haha, 3 almost same answers in 20 second spread :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehensions can also do filtering:

```
mainlist = [line.strip() for line in f if "New changes" not in line]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can filter within the list comprehension :

```
mainlist = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip() !=  "New changes"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    mainlist = []
    for line in f:
        s = line.strip()
        if s != "New changes":
            mainlist.append(s)
```

If anyone has a more pythonic way to do this, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Comprehensions can also accept a condition. Try:

```
mainlist = [line.strip() for line in f if line != "New changes"]
```

or

```
mainlist = [line.strip() for line in f if "New changes" not in line]
```

Comment: the first is now working on my machine. you are missing a `.strip()`.

Comment: These two weren't supposed to work the same. OP didn't elaborate on what *line matches a string* means (strict equality or presence of a pattern), so I gave code for both variants

Answer (score 0):

Just to be different here is an incantation from the schools of reduce and regex:

```
import re
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
  mainlist = reduce(lambda x, y: x+re.findall("^((?!.*New changes).*)\n?$", y), f.readlines(), [])
```